# php for next button loading same page

Tags: php, html

I am a PHP newbie.
I have 2 php files.
**First is mags.php**

```
<?php 

$formurl = "food.php" ;
$viewurl = "try.php" ;

$mytitl = $_POST["magname"]; 

$cur_page  = 1 ;
$page_dir = 'next' ;

$params = http_build_query(array('magname' => $mytitl, 'magpage' => $cur_page, 'pagedir' => $page_dir), '', '&' );


header( "Location: " . $viewurl . "?" . $params);

exit ;

?>
```

**Second is try.php**

```
<?php

$mytitl  = $_GET["magname"];
$cur_page  = $_GET["magpage"];
$page_dir  = $_GET["pagedir"];
$mytitldir = ("./Books/$mytitl/") ;

$myDirectory = opendir($mytitldir);
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;  }

closedir($myDirectory);
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
sort($dirArray);

if ($page_dir == 'next') {
    $cur_page++;

    if ($cur_page == $indexCount) {
        $cur_page = 2;
    }
} else {
    $cur_page--;
    if ($cur_page == 1) {
        $cur_page = 3;
        }
}

$mag = "$mytitldir$dirArray[$cur_page]" ;

print ("Mag Dir = $mytitldir <br>\n") ;

print("Magazine Page = $mag <br>\n"); 
print("Page Direction = $page_dir <br>\n"); 
print("Page # = $cur_page <br>\n"); 

echo  "<img src= \"$mag" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"400\" width=\"400\" /><br />";

 ?>  

 <form method="post" action="try.php">  
<input type="hidden"  name="pagedir" value="next" />            
<input type="hidden" name= $cur_page value= 3 />
<input type="hidden" name="magname" value= $mytitl />
<input type="submit" img src="Next_Arrow.png" width="60" height="75"   alt="Next"   value="Next Page  "/>
<td width="60" valign="middle"></td></form>
```

My problem is that I need to load the same try.php when user clicks on Next button.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to check a little how forms work in html see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp for example.

Comment: I've edited my answer after spotting several errors in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change form method to get.....

```
<form method="get" action="try.php">
```

Edit:

Your script is fetching the values from $_GET[] server variable so if your form uses the post method $_GET will be empty when the form is submitted.

Edit:

```
<input type="hidden" name= $cur_page value= 3 />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="manpage" value="<?php echo $cur_page; ?>" />
```

Edit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="magname" value= $mytitl />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="magname" value=<?php echo $mytitl; ?> />
```

Comment: Downvoted: this is a very poor answer, no guidlines, it doesn't specify where the op should make the change

Comment: thank you for accepting my comment and editing your post, I've undownvoted your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* sure what you're trying to accomplish here... Please do give more information...

If you want the form to process the php that is on the webpage, you don't have to put an `action` URL, but the way you have it right now should work. But as mentioned, change the `method` to `GET` because that is the type of variables you are processing through the page.

Or you could just change all the `$_GET` variables to `$_POST` variables and keep the `method` as `POST`. That way you wouldn't have problems with confusing your passing variables between `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: When try.php loads up first time, it displays properly. What I want is when next button is pressed, the variable $cur_page should change and the webpage should rload with new display

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with this conditinal statement:
`if ($cur_page == $indexCount) {
        $cur_page = 2;
    }
} else {
    $cur_page--;
    if ($cur_page == 1) {
        $cur_page = 3;
        }
}` because from what I am understanding you're sending the user to different pages depending on if it's a different value... Please give us more information on what you are trying to do with your current code.

Comment: Ok. Lets get it straight. User logs in to a site where a directory listing of books are listed. When user clicks on a selection, the selected book folder name is passed on to mags.php as magname. This is then transferred to try.php where selected book's first page is displayed. Here $cur_page is the first page and $index_count is the number of total pages. $cur_page must start at 2. To view next page, user clicks on Next Page button and $cur_page should increment and  next page should be displayed. This is what's not happening. $page_dir keeps track of page navigation whether prev or next.